# Unterminated attribute selector

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

I tried to use the `@each` sass function, but im getting always the error `Unterminated attribute selector for track`. I have no idea, where is the fault in my code.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item-sliding [attr.track]="green" >
        <ion-item>
          Item
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="left">


          <button ion-button (click)="favorite(item)">Favorite</button>
          <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="share(item)">Share</button>
        </ion-item-options>

        <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button (click)="unread(item)">Unread</button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
```

**SASS CSS CODE**

```
@each $track, $value in auxiliary-categories() {
  ion-item-sliding [track=#{$track}] ion-label {
    border-left: 5px solid $value;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
 }


 $categories: (
    ionic: color($colors, primary),
    angular: #AC282B,
    communication: #8E8D93,
    red: #FE4C52,
    yellow: #FED035,
    green: #69BB7B,
    blau: #3BC7C4,
 );

 @function auxiliary-categories() {
     @return map-remove($categories);
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a `green` property in you component class? If not, and if `green` is used as a literal string, try `track="green"` or `[attr.track]="'green'"`.

Comment: I have tried both..not working, same error. Currently green is a property and defined in the component..   `green = "green";`

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have got the fix.  `$categories` and the `@function auxiliary-categories()` have to be defined before `@each...`